# How to create google meeting link via API without calendar integration

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api

I want to create a Google meeting link but don't want it to be added to google calendar. How it can be achieved

Below is the code i am using currently

```
const meet = await calendar.events.insert({
      calendarId: 'primary',
      conferenceDataVersion: 1,
      requestBody: {
        summary: description,
        description,
        start: {
          dateTime: new Date()
          timeZone: 'UTC',
        },
        end: {
          dateTime: new Date(),
          timeZone: 'UTC',
        },
        guestsCanSeeOtherGuests: true,
        conferenceData: {
          createRequest: {
            conferenceSolutionKey: {
              type: 'hangoutsMeet',
            },
            requestId: 'kkuhbiiih9099',
          },
        },
        reminders: {
          useDefault: true,
        },
      },
    });
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.